# Python Video Manipulation

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg

I'm new with python and I want to do is receive UDP stream (streaming from VLC, H264) and make any modifications to the video and display it (Python 2.7).

I used openCV (openCV 2.4.9) and I can receive video frames and also modify it. Now I need to do is create a video file using these frames and display it and I don't need to save both frames and the video.

I tried *FFMPEG,FFPLAY* and it works on saved video frames.

I appreciate that if you can point out the steps or any other alternatives.

First of all sorry about my explanation early. Here is what I've tried:

1. Receive UDP video stream.
2. Modify the video stream: I used openCV and get video frames from stream and modified them it working.

   ```
   cap = cv2.VideoCapture("udp://224.1.1.1:1234")
   while(cap.isOpened()):
       success, image = cap.read()
       ...
       cv2.imwrite("./frames/frame%d.jpeg" %count, image)
       count += 1
   ```
3. Create video and display: I tried FFMPEG and FFPLAY

   ```
   command1 = 'ffmpeg -i ./frames/frame%d.jpeg -c:v libx264 -vf fps=23.97 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f rawvideo -'
   command2 = 'ffplay -'

   pipe1 = sp.Popen(command1,stdout=sp.PIPE)  
   pipe2 = sp.Popen(command2,stdin=pipe1.stdout)
   ```

These steps working but I cannot save frames or video file physically. I need to do is after step 2 direcly pass video frames to FFMPEG, FFPLAY to play without saving them in frames folder.

Comment: [cv2.VideoWriter](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videowriter) and a [sample](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/samples/python2/turing.py)

Answer (score 1):

```
command1 = 'ffmpeg -y -f image2pipe -vcodec mjpeg -r 23.97 -i - -vcodec mpeg4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -r 23.97 -f avi - '
command2 = 'ffplay -'

pipe1 = sp.Popen(command1,stdin=sp.PIPE,stdout=sp.PIPE)
pipe2 = sp.Popen(command2,stdin=pipe1.stdout)


While(cap.isOpened()):
    success,raw_image = cap.read()
    pil_im = Image.fromarray(raw_image)
    pil_im.save(pipe1.stdin ,'JPEG')
```

This works for me but some colour problems.

Answer (score 0):

you can use cv2.imshow() to show your processed frames directly rather than passing them to ffplay or ffmpeg,for example instead of writing the frames in your code

```
import cv2 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("udp://224.1.1.1:1234") 
while(cap.isOpened()):
        success,image = cap.read()
        ......
        ......
        cv2.imshow("Video", image)
```